# Repetition of "and he begat sons and daughters:"

Tags: exegesis, genesis, adam, genealogy, noah

While reading Genesis 5, we can read the development of human race from Adam to Noah, bridging the gap between the two.

During that passage, there's an expression mentioned often

> (...) and he begat sons and daughters:

What's the purpose of such repetition?

Comment: It's a literary device called [epistrophe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epistrophe). For more details you could ask at the [English Language and Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MattGutting just asked there as well - https://english.stackexchange.com/q/520868/263630

Comment: not really an answer because I feel this is opinion based but it could be to show that they are following the first commandment to: `Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though we cannot be sure why that phrase is repeated, we can certainly deduce that it's inclusion serves to illustrate that the World was being rapidly filled. This may have also been used to contrast the large populous in contrast to there being only Noah found worthy of escaping the flood.

> Genesis 6:5 through 13 KJV  And GOD saw that the wickedness of man was great in the earth, and that every imagination of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually. And it repented the LORD that he had made man on the earth, and it grieved him at his heart. And the LORD said, I will destroy man whom I have created from the face of the earth; both man, and beast, and the creeping thing, and the fowls of the air; for it repenteth me that I have made them. ***But Noah found grace in the eyes of the LORD***. These are the generations of Noah: ***Noah was a just man and perfect in his generations, and Noah walked with God***. And Noah begat three sons, Shem, Ham, and Japheth. The earth also was corrupt before God, and the earth was filled with violence. And God looked upon the earth, and, behold, it was corrupt; for all flesh had corrupted his way upon the earth. And God said unto Noah, The end of all flesh is come before me; for the earth is filled with violence through them; and, behold, I will destroy them with the earth.

It is also worthy to note that only Noah found Grace; and yet God also saved his three sons and their wives. Later in Genesis we find that through these three sons both good and evil, were continued in the World. 
Why would God continue both in the World? I cannot say for sure, but it would seem to me that unless both were preserved there would remain no freedom of choice.

Answer (score 1):

That repetition is called epistrophe which is an optional repetition to make a point.

This comes in a context where humans were expelled from paradise (where they were given a clear command we can read in Genesis 1:28, "fruitful and multiply. Fill the earth and govern it. Reign over the fish in the sea, the birds in the sky..."), fear and shame entered the world and there's a sign of redemption.

Even though we can't be sure or know what's in human hearts, i believe by reinforcing the idea humans are now following what God commanded while they were in paradise and not questioning Him, they are either trying to please Him to compensate for their wrongdoings or simply because they trust that's the best.

Quoting Thomas Brooks (1824). “The select works of ... Thomas Brooks".

> Till men have faith in Christ, their best services are but glorious sins.